# can not find symbol Language.ENGLISH

Tags: java, netbeans-8, languagetool

I am using jlanguagetool for checking grammar of my text and 
I am new to this. I have added `langaugetool-core-2.5.jar` in libraries. But I get error in this line of code 
`JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(Language.ENGLISH);` 
at ENGLISH, saying "can not find symbol". What could be the reason for that? Am I using wrong jar file?

Comment: The current version of languagetool is 3.4.  Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: Please make sure that {{langaugetool-core-2.5.jar}} is added to the project as a dependency and make it available in the classpath

Comment: You really need to visit http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api and study the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you try to initialize the JLanguageTool is invalid. Correct way of initializing the JLanguageTool is

> JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool( new BritishEnglish());

*BritishEnglish* is available in the dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
 <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
 <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note :** Please go through the complete documentation before start the development as @Jim Garrison mention.

*Additional Dependencies*
[image: Additional Dependencies]

Comment: it gives same error of "cannot find symbol" on BritishEnglish()

Comment: 'BritishEnglish' is available in a separate jar file : `language-en` Please add it as a project dependency.

Comment: I am using netbeans, can you please tell me how to add dependency in it? and I can't find 'language-en' jar file.

Comment: You can download the jar file form maven central http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/languagetool/language-en/2.5/language-en-2.5.jar

Comment: Right click on your project with the Cup Icon. Click Properties. Go to Libraries. Tab Compile. Add JAR/Folder. Select File.

Comment: Thank you so much @KeshanDeSilva for providing link. But I am getting errors after compiling:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: morfologik/stemming/IStemmer
 at org.languagetool.language.English.getTagger(English.java:91)
 at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.<init>(JLanguageTool.java:205)
 at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.<init>(JLanguageTool.java:182)
 at jlanguagetoolsgrammarcheck.JLanguageToolsGrammarCheck.main(JLanguageToolsGrammarCheck.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: morfologik.stemming.IStemmer

Comment: last line says: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @Igniter it seems that language-en has some dependencies; you need to add all those jars to your project. Please check the maven central - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.languagetool/language-en/2.5

Comment: I have updated my answer with an image which shows the list of dependencies for the language-en

Comment: But in this link, it shows only few dependencies which I have added but does not help.

Comment: There are more; please see the image attached to my answer

Comment: No, there are more. There are indirect dependencies. For ex: org.languagetool » languagetool-core is define as a dependency. For that there are another 7 compile time dependencies. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.languagetool/languagetool-core/2.5 like wise you have to add all the indirect dependencies as well.

Comment: BTW; if you find my answer resolve your initial problem make sure to mark my answer as correct answer.

Comment: OMG after adding lots of dependencies, it finally worked.. Thank you so much @KeshanDeSilva :)